# sighandler and other threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals

1. Is it possible to handle a sighandler when currently handling another signal?
2. Is it possible to handle a sighandler when currently handling another thread execution?

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the answers are right in the documentation [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html)

> A process-directed signal may be delivered to any one of the threads that does not currently have the signal blocked.  If more than one of the threads has the signal unblocked, then the kernel chooses an arbitrary thread to which to deliver the signal.

Comment: Thanks chris. So as I understand it. If the program have multiple thread it can handle the signal and at the same time continue to run,correct?

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing. If you are asking if only one of your threads will be interrupted to handle the signal request, then it appears as if the documentation supports that. However, this depends on the version of Unix that you are using. Under Linux 2.6, a single thread is interrupted and the other threads continue to execute. But, I believe in earlier versions the entire process was interrupted to handle the signal.